# Item highlight does not persist in ListView using SherlokListFragmet

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm using [SherlokListFragment](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for creating a `ListView` inside a `Fragment`.

I setted the adapter:

```
adapter = new ServiceArrayAdapter(getActivity(), ((ACT_ListProvider)this.getActivity()).getItems());        
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and I did a customization of `ListView`

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

getListView().setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
```

When an item is clicked I call this code:

```
getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
```

All the customization are added to my `ListView` correctly, except the selector. I have already use that selector in other project, and  it works good (but I have always use it from xml layout), so I can't understand why it is not added to my `ListView`. Where can be the problem?

**EDIT:**

In particoular I want that if an item is clicked the focus remains over it, while now it disappears immediately. 
The code of my selector is the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
```

Comment: you want the clicked element changes its background colour?

Comment: I want that if the element is selected the focus remains over the item, while now if I select an item the focus immediately disappears

Comment: have you tried with state_activated?

Comment: as item for your selector. In the place of state_selected, for instance

Comment: I obtain the same result :(

Comment: I see. If I were you, I will start keeping things simple in order to track down the issue. For instance you can avoid combining status and try only a status at time

Comment: do you have any buttons in item of list?

Comment: @blackbelt I have used that selector many times, but the listview was always defined in the xml. Now, instead, since ListFragment returns me the ListView, I'm not defining it in the xml

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't getting what I wanted so I kept on digging and came up with a "cheap" solution which might not be the best practice but does the job. I wanted the item to be highlighted when selected and the color should go away when other item is selected from the listFragment. This is what worked for me- I defined a static View V; and initialized it `V = new View(getActivity());` Then inside my :

```
onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

            V.setBackgroundResource(0);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.BLUE);
            V = v;
```

Comment: when I release the button the background remains. Moreover, if you are recycling view in ListView you'll may background setted also to other items that you have never selected.